# Obtain $\TeX$ code as in `StandardForm`

Tags: latex, output

This is a question very close related to 
[Breaking up long equations in TeXForm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40200/breaking-up-long-equations-in-texform/). Last time, because @Adam doest not present a clear goal for this problem, as stated by Massimo Ortolano

> there's no general solution to your question, especially if the splitting has to be done for a publication where clarity is of utmost importance.

I think imitate the way implemented by *Mathematica* in `StandardForm` is a reasonable result for this problem.

Consider following expression:

```
Sinh[b]*(-10*b*Cosh[b/2]^2*(-1 + 2*Cosh[2*b*xm])*Sin[b] + 
   80*b*Cosh[b/2]*Sin[b/2]*Sin[b*xm]*Sinh[b*xm] + 
   (-160 - 16*(-10 + b^4)*Cos[b] + (80*I)*Cos[(1 + I)*b] + 
     16*b^4*Cos[b*(1 - 2*xm)] - (80*I)*Cosh[(1 + I)*b] - 20*b*Sin[b] - 
     64*b^3*Sin[b] + (10 - 20*I)*b*Sin[(1 + I)*b] + 40*b*Sin[b*(1 - 2*xm)] - 
     (20*I)*b*Sin[b*((1 - I) - 2*xm)] + (20*I)*b*Sin[b*((1 + I) - 2*xm)] + 
     40*b*Sin[2*b*xm] + (20 - 10*I)*b*Sinh[(1 + I)*b] - 
     4*b*(10 - 10*Cos[b] + 4*b^3*Sin[b] - 10*Sin[b]*Sinh[b])*Sinh[2*b*xm])/4) + 
 (Cosh[b]*(b*Cosh[b*xm]^2*(20 - 20*Cos[b] + 2*Sin[b]*(4*b^3 + 10*Sinh[b])) + 
    (-40*b + 100*b*Cos[b] - (10 + 20*I)*b*Cos[(1 + I)*b] - 
      60*b*Cos[b*(1 - 2*xm)] + 10*b*Cos[b*((1 - I) - 2*xm)] + 
      10*b*Cos[b*((1 + I) - 2*xm)] - (10 - 20*I)*b*Cosh[(1 + I)*b] + 
      240*Sin[b] - 16*b^4*Sin[b] - 40*Sin[(1 + I)*b] + (40*I)*Sinh[(1 + I)*b] - 
      320*b*Sin[b/2]*Sin[b*xm]*Sinh[b/2]*Sinh[b*xm] + 
      4*b*(10 - 10*Cos[b] + 4*b^3*Sin[b] + 10*Sin[b]*Sinh[b])*Sinh[b*xm]^2 - 
      20*b*(-3 + Cosh[b])*Sin[b]*Sinh[2*b*xm])/2 - 
    10*Cosh[b/2]^2*(2*b*Cos[b] - 2*b*Cos[b*(1 - 2*xm)] + 
      2*Sin[b]*(4 + b*Sinh[2*b*xm]))))/2
```

By adjusting the width of the window, several ways to break the expression is given by *Mathematica*. The question is whether it is possible to obtain $TeX$ codes equivalent to these `StandardForm` outputs.

[image: long]
[image: short]

Comment: Line breaking is done "on the fly" by FrontEnd, its effects are not visible on box level, on which conversion to $TeX$ occurs. I don't know whether there's any way of accessing FrontEnd's algorithms. I'm afraid only way to achieve what you want, is to re-implement line breaking on box level from scratch. Best thing we have for formatting on box level is Leonid's [CodeFormatter](https://github.com/lshifr/CodeFormatter), but as far as I know it mostly pretty-prints "code" not "mathematical expressions".

Comment: @jkuczm do you have any idea on how the FrontEnd break the lines. I think it is better implemented than `breqn` latex package.

Comment: Unfortunately all I know is what can be gathered from details of [Line Breaking options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TextLayoutOptions.html#169683403) especially ["Details" section of `LinebreakAdjustments`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinebreakAdjustments.html#DetailsAndOptions) which gives general overview of how it works and how to customize it, but not much on how it's implemented.